# i want specific area name provided pincode of that area

Tags: google-maps, geocode, postal-code

I need name of an area and city I pass the postal code as a parameter.

For example I tried

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=382340&components=country:in&sensor=false

for a postal code in India.

Although this is giving multiple results with irrelevant data. I could get coordinates using the geocode API. I do not need coordinates though, just the area name corresponding to the postal code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exact area name would you like as an answer to your sample query?

Comment: there is a unique region name associated with each postal code...i mean one-to-one mapping is there between name and postal code e.g 382340 is postal code for "kubernagar" area... so i want name "kubernagar" if i supply 382340

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=india&components=postal_code:400003&sensor=false
```

This returns the correct results, which could be further trimmed to get the relevant data.

Comment: What if I want the map image of it as a link , when I type the pincode ?

Comment: I mean , when you type the pincode in google maps , it has the option to get the link and it returns the iframe.

Comment: This returns the *city* name, not the area, anything for that?